# How to create Enum for the given objects

Tags: java, enums

I have a class called - SparqlResource.java and in the class I am instantiating four objects like this-

```
public static final SparqlResource MARK_SIMPLE_TYPE = new SparqlResource("ldmext/MarkSimpleType.rq");
public static final SparqlResource FORTRESS_HAS_ENVOY = new SparqlResource("ldmext/FortressHasEnvoy.rq");
public static final SparqlResource FORTRESS_HAS_GUARD = new SparqlResource("ldmext/FortressHasGuard.rq");
public static final SparqlResource FORTRESS_HAS_PORT = new SparqlResource("ldmext/FortressHasPort.rq");
```

Now from another class - JenaLanguageConstructor.java, I am referencing these objects like this-

```
runOneQuery(SparqlResource.MARK_SIMPLE_TYPE, true);
runOneQuery(SparqlResource.FORTRESS_HAS_ENVOY, true);
runOneQuery(SparqlResource.FORTRESS_HAS_GUARD, true);
runOneQuery(SparqlResource.FORTRESS_HAS_PORT, true);
```

Now my question is is there any way I can use enums to achieve this, if so then can any one please give me a sample code which I can use to create the enum?

Comment: See enum doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html, enums can contain values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public enum SPARQLENUM {
    MARK_SIMPLE_TYPE("ldmext/MarkSimpleType.rq") ,
    FORTRESS_HAS_ENVOY("ldmext/FortressHasEnvoy.rq") ,
    FORTRESS_HAS_GUARD("ldmext/FortressHasGuard.rq") ,
    FORTRESS_HAS_PORT("ldmext/FortressHasPort.rq");

    private String value;

    private SPARQLENUM(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }


}
```

And you can call it this way:

```
SPARQLENUM.FORTRESS_HAS_ENVOY.getValue()
```

---

**EDITED**

If you need the `SparqlResource` object, you can create the enum this way:

```
public enum SPARQLENUM {
    MARK_SIMPLE_TYPE(new SparqlResource("ldmext/MarkSimpleType.rq")) ,
    FORTRESS_HAS_ENVOY(new SparqlResource("ldmext/FortressHasEnvoy.rq")) ,
    FORTRESS_HAS_GUARD(new SparqlResource("ldmext/FortressHasGuard.rq")) ,
    FORTRESS_HAS_PORT(new SparqlResource("ldmext/FortressHasPort.rq"));

    private SparqlResource value;

    private SPARQLENUM(SparqlResource value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


    public SparqlResource getValue(){
        return value;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, creating an enum wouldn't be that hard:

```
enum MyEnum {
  VALUE1("name 1"),
  VALUE2("name 2");

  private String name;

  private MyEnum(String n) {
    name = n;
  }

  //whatever else you need
}
```

Comment: hi, can you please let me how can I call one of the enums from the other class JenaLanguageConstructor.java.

Comment: @SomSarkar you use it just as any other class, e.g. `runOneQuery( MyEnum e, boolean flag)` and then `runOneQuery(VALUE1, true);`